# Microsoft sql 2012 - is there a maximum query result?

Tags: sql-server, max

I can't seem to find an answer to this in Google or Stackoverflow.
Is there a maximum size to the results from a query (specifically for MSSQL 2012)? If so, how can I find it? Is it in some settings somewhere?

Comment: Are you taking about the results viewed in SSMS or what ?

Comment: Why do you ask?  Realistically, any limit is going to be the result of your hardware and your query.  If you are, for example, doing a sort, your limit will likely depend on how much space your `tempdb` can consume (as would things like hash joins).

Comment: Hi Prdp, thanks for answering. I'm actually referring to the dataset returned as a result to the query, regardless of where it's going (SSMS's output as file or table view, or result to a code's query string). So basically you're saying there's no limit.

Comment: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). There is no limit on the number of rows returned by the query.